# How to launch a MainActivity from LaunchActivity

Tags: android-studio, android-activity

Essentially if the user is already logged in to my application, I want MainActivity to launch from LaunchActivity, but I don't know how to do that.

I'm using google firebase to authenticate the user, but it is mostly the android studio code I am lost on. Both MainActivity and Launch Activity extend AppCompatActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);
    if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
        startActivity(MainActivity);
        finish();
    } else {//the rest of my code follows here
```

It gives me the error: "Cannot resolve variable symbol MainActivity", it occurs for the line startActivity(MainActivity);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);
    if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {//the rest of my code follows here
```

try this

Comment: That was it! I forgot intents have to go in the startActivity() function. I feel quite silly